# Fullcalendar dropdown. How to make it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, bootstrap-datepicker

Is there any way to make fullcalendar make dropdown functionality same as Bootstrap Datepicker? Like on this picture.
[image]

Comment: You can follow this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355833/how-can-i-use-fullcalendar-io-as-a-type-date-picker it might help. You can find my comment too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already an open and accepted issue, requesting this, that you can follow here: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=225

Anyway, you could use, for example, jqueryUi datePicker and detect when its changed using onSelect event. Then, you just need to change the date of your fullCalendar.

So you could have something like:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
       var selectedDate = this.value;
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', selectedDate );
  }
});
```